# Custom ETag algorithm for asset fingerprinting

Tags: scala, playframework

How to specify the ETag algorithm used for asset fingerprinting in Play without using third-party plugins?

For example, specify that the ETag is to be the environment variable `BUILD_NUMBER`, the GitHub revision number of the file, and its time/date?  To know how to do the GitHub revision bit would be really great. :)

Related questions: [Embed ETag in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310613/embed-etag-in-url) & [Automatically Insert ETag (asset fingerprinting) as comment at top of the resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310543/automatically-insert-etag-asset-fingerprinting-as-comment-at-top-of-the-resour)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically Insert ETag (asset fingerprinting) as comment at top of the resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310543/automatically-insert-etag-asset-fingerprinting-as-comment-at-top-of-the-resour)

Comment: @applicius This question is about ETag itself (how it is calculated) and that question is about putting ETag in a different place (in a file rather than as a HTTP header or in the URL). Makes sense?

Comment: I think I would really be much nice to gather questions so close in one.

Answer (score 0):

At present there is no configuration possibility to specify what ETag algorithm to use with the Play API.

The [`Assets` class](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/controllers/Assets.scala) can be extended and overridden to keep all the benefits of the aggressive caching that Play does when changing the ETag algorithm.

The `BUILD_NUMBER` can be passed in to the algorithm and the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) can be used to obtain the revision number for any file.