# Automatically Insert ETag (asset fingerprinting) as comment at top of the resource

Tags: scala, playframework

How to ask Play to automatically insert the file's ETag as a comment near the top of the file without using third party plugins?

E.g., for a HTML resource, insert `<!-- ETag: 1234 -->` at the top of the `<head>` tag.

Answers on how to do this with Play framework's built-in public assets routing/fingerprinting support would be great too. :)

Related questions:
[Custom ETag algorithm for asset fingerprinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310520/custom-etag-algorithm-for-asset-fingerprinting) & [Embed ETag in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310613/embed-etag-in-url)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embed ETag in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310613/embed-etag-in-url)

Comment: @applicius This question is about ETag itself (how it is calculated) and that question is about putting ETag in a different place (in a file rather than as a HTTP header or in the URL). Makes sense?

Comment: I think I would really be much nice to gather questions so close in one.

Comment: @applicius That was my original plan however I realised that maybe it was too much to ask in a single question. Some may have answers for only one and not for the other two. For example, someone may know how to configure the URL behaviour but not how to insert ETag at the top of every resource.

Comment: A bunch of 3 three question is not nicer for me.

Answer (score 0):

In `conf/routes` add the following:

```
GET  /resources/*file  controllers.Resources.at(file)
```

In `app/controllers/Resources` controller:

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._

object Resources extends Controller {
  def at(path: String): Action = {
    // calculate ETag
    val etag = ETag(path)
    // stream file with ETag inserted
    Ok(... <!-- ETag: etag --> ...)
  }
}
```