# Embed ETag in URL

Tags: scala, playframework

A question about asset fingerprinting in Play.

How to ask Play to embed ETags in URLs without using a third-party plugin?

E.g., if `/css/resource.css` had the ETag of `1234`, then it would become `/css/responsive-1234.css`.

Related questions: [Custom ETag algorithm for asset fingerprinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310520/custom-etag-algorithm-for-asset-fingerprinting) & [Automatically Insert ETag (asset fingerprinting) as comment at top of the resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310543/automatically-insert-etag-asset-fingerprinting-as-comment-at-top-of-the-resour)

Comment: Have you looked at using regex in your routes? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaRouting

Answer (score 0):

There'll be the "out" routing and the "in" reverse routing.  Firstly the "out" routing:

```
  package controllers

  import play.api.mvc._

  object Resources extends Controller {

    def fingerprintedUrl(path: String): String = {
      // calculates ETag and add to URL path
      val pathWithEtag = addEtagToPath(path)
      pathWithEtag
    }
  }
```

Then in templates use the following for example:

```
 <script src="@Resources.fingerprintedUrl("js/toolkit.js")"></script>
```

Now the reverse routing, add the following to the same controller:

```
  def at(path: String): Action = {
    val pathWithoutEtag = removeEtagFromPath(path)
    Assets.at("/public", pathWithoutEtag)
  }
```

Then in `routes`:

```
  GET  /resources/*file  controllers.Resources.at(file)
```